# 'x' must be numeric error when converting time interval to string labels by cut() function in R

Tags: r, time, cut

I have a column 'Incident_Time' representing time in a data frame in R.

when I call the str() function on the column it says something like this

> str(crime_data$Incident_Time)
>
> Factor w/ 1439 levels "00:01:00","00:02:00",..: 840 945 1140 981 1260 969 1020 840 980 765 ...

I want to convert this column into string type such that if the time is less than 12:00:00, it should get modified to the string "morning" , if time is between 12:00:00 and 6:00:00 , it is "daylight" and so on.

I typed the following commands:

```
    time.tag <- chron(times=c("00:00:00", "06:00:00", "12:00:00", "18:00:00", "23:59:59"))

    labels <- c("Early Morning", "Morning", "Evening", "Night")

    crime_data$Incident_Time_Range <- cut(crime_data$Incident_Time, breaks = time.tag, labels, include.lowest = TRUE )
```

Then the following error occurred:

> Error in cut.default(crime_data$Incident_Time, breaks = time.tag, labels,  : 
>     'x' must be numeric

Please help me to identify the problem. Thank You.

Comment: Could you give us a sample of your dataset with `dput()`?

Comment: Here is the summary : https://pastebin.com/dyjDBD7y

Comment: Here all scripts: https://pastebin.com/cdkfivmC

Comment: It is the dataset from San Francisco crime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unverified as there is no sample data, but you shouldn't have your incident time as a factor. Convert to time:

```
crime_data$Incident_Time <- chron(times=as.character(crime_data$Incident_Time))
```

Then run your existing code

Answer (score 0):

To provide a complete example.

**Example Data**

```
sampletime<-chron(times=as.character(as.ITime(Sys.time()+sample(86400,100))))
```

No modifications needed to code but it would not work until I converted `sampletime` to class `times` by using `chron`. I believe cut will not work if your data is not the same `class`.

```
cut(sampletime, breaks = time.tag, labels, include.lowest = TRUE )

[1] Early Morning Evening       Evening       Evening      
  [5] Morning       Night         Evening       Night        
  [9] Night         Morning       Early Morning Early Morning
 [13] Evening       Early Morning Morning       Early Morning
 [17] Evening       Morning       Early Morning Evening      
....
```

Comment: `data.table` needed for `as.ITime`.